# Sass not compile optimize

Tags: css, sass

Sass compiled a huge file for me and it can be mush smaller!!
I did not find anything in the compiler settings! Most likely, the problem is with the compiler.
Maybe the problem is with my code.

My scss file:

```scss
@mixin flex {
  display: flex;
  dynamic- { flex: 1 1 }
  shrink-  { flex: 0 1 }
  fixed-   { flex: 0 0 }
  grow-    { flex: 0 1 }
}
column- {
  @include flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
row- {
  @include flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

compiled css

```css
column- {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
column- dynamic- {
  flex: 1 1;
}
column- shrink- {
  flex: 0 1;
}
column- fixed- {
  flex: 0 0;
}
column- grow- {
  flex: 0 1;
}

row- {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
row- dynamic- {
  flex: 1 1;
}
row- shrink- {
  flex: 0 1;
}
row- fixed- {
  flex: 0 0;
}
row- grow- {
  flex: 0 1;
}
```

My css optimized!

```css
column- ,row-{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
column- dynamic- ,row- dynamic{
  flex: 1 1;
}
column- shrink- ,row- shrink-{
  flex: 0 1;
}
column- fixed- ,row- fixed-{
  flex: 0 0;
}
column- grow- ,row- grow-{
  flex: 0 1;
}
```

I am using vscode and linux Sass live compiler extension
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would Sass optimize your CSS? That's the job of a CSS optimizer (such as [`csso`](https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html)).

Comment: Compilers usually have to do optimization as well, for example c/c++ compilers!

Comment: C/C++ is an entirely different thing, and they don't _have_ to do optimization, it's an option. There is no such option in the Sass compiler.

Comment: For anyone looking this up, the reason Sass isn't even allowed to do this kind of optimization, is that *technically* an element could match "column- grow-" AND "row- shrink-", and the optimized css would change which style is applied. (Because the order of the styles gets shuffled around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code must be change and sass compile don't have any problems

```
@mixin flex {
  display: flex;
  dynamic- { flex: 1 1 }
   shrink- { flex: 0 1 }
    fixed- { flex: 0 0 }
     grow- { flex: 0 1 }
}

column-, row-{
  @include flex;
}
column-{
  flex-direction: column;
}
```